# Random access to hash map values

Tags: c++, c

What's the best way to design such a container, which can support randomized value access? but the container has to support other operations, such as insert key/value pairs and remove by key, with the best possible time performance.

One way to do this is to combine hash map with array, but if hash map is used, what's the best way to do random access of hash map values, i.e., without generating a key.

Comment: You always have to generate a key. No matter what the language.

Comment: You can use `std::advance(my_hash_map.begin(), 10);` with linear time.

Comment: That's say the question is language agnostic, what's the best way to design such a container, which can support randomised value access? but the container can't be a vector or array, as it has to support other operations, such as insert key/value pairs and remove by key.

Comment: When you say randomized value access, what do you mean?  Also, vector/array totally support insert key/value pairs and remove by key if you're crafty.

Comment: Randomized value access means 'containerInstance.random()' returns a random element. Vector/array supports insert and remove, but random insert performance is not as good as hash map(table).

Comment: You want contradictory things.  You want random access *and* key value pair type access.  You can't have both and they don't make sense when grouped together.

Comment: A similar question: http://www.sureinterview.com/shwqst/1019005

Comment: Found a similar question: http://www.quora.com/What-data-structures-support-insertion-deletion-and-selection-of-a-random-element-with-a-math-O-1-math-time-complexity-bound

Comment: @user965942 - Random access means that accessing any element in the structure is done in O(1).

Comment: @EdS. yes, that's why the question was asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about data structures, and not existing language support - then you just have to design a data structure to support that.

You can do that, for example, by implementing a hash map which will hold, in addition, an array of pointers to its members. You can then translate random access operators to that array, and maintain it with every insertion or removal (that is of course a general idea, some implementation details omitted).

Some languages support traversing the data structures through iterators. Although looping on an iterator for a random amount of times is not really random access (performance-wise), it will give you the same result in more time.

I would say your question sounds like some algorithms' coursework homework. Why would you want to do it in the real life? What is the problem you're trying to solve?

**edit**

In the comments you phrased the problem as:

> what's the best way to design such a container, which can support
>   randomized value access? but the container has to support other
>   operations, such as insert key/value pairs and remove by key, with the
>   best possible performance.

My suggestions above hold, but the question is what is the trade-off. If the "best performance" is time-wise, then my suggestion with the array gives you that. If the best performance is memory-wise then the iterating over the tree would give you that, that's my other suggestion.

In general, when you come to a need to design a new data structure, you need to answer the following questions:

1. What are the operations required?
2. What is the time complexity required, **for each** operation?
3. What is the memory complexity required for the structure?
4. Which is more important, memory or time?

Sometimes you just can't do in O(1) without additional memory. Sometimes you can do in O(1) with additional O(n) memory, but you can make it with O(lg n) memory if you compromise on O(lg n) time. There are trade offs that you have to make your decision about, I don't know them.

So my first suggestion (combining a BST or hash with an array of pointers to its nodes) does all the operations of the BST (map) or hash with the standard complexity of BST/hash operations, and all the read operations of array with the standard complexity (i.e.: random access in O(1) time). Write operations of the array will be with complexity of map/hash, and additional memory footprint is O(n).

My second suggestion has no additional memory footprint, but the "random" access is pseudo random: you can just iterate to the point you want instead of directly accessing it. That would make your random access in O(n) while zero additional coding, or wasting memory.

Name of the game? Trade-offs.

Comment: The question is still a valid question though, suppose I'm a library writer, and specification says that I have to support key/value add, delete by key and value random access operations in the container. I had the same idea as yours, but may not be the best, would like to get all O(1) performance as well with no additional memory footrpint.

Comment: As I said - this kind of data structure is very uncommon and you have to build it yourself. The standard libraries provide the basic standard data structures, one of the things you have to do as a programmer is to combine them into what you actually want and need. You can't get O(1) performance implementing random access over a BST without additional memory foot print, unless you implement your BST in an array (and that's not how BST's are usually implemented).

Comment: Thanks, it's not coursework although it may sound so. I'm aware that I have to build it myself. The question is language agnostic, let me rephrase it, what's the best way to design such a container, which can support randomised value access? but the container has to support other operations, such as insert key/value pairs and remove by key, with the best possible performance.

Comment: Many thanks, came across this post http://www.quora.com/What-data-structures-support-insertion-deletion-and-selection-of-a-random-element-with-a-math-O-1-math-time-complexity-bound, which suggests hash map (insert+delete) with array (randomized access).

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to inspect the key portion of a unorederd_map, use it's iterators.

Comment: `map` isn't a hash container - perhaps you meant `unordered_map`?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "without inserting a new element", then `find()` is the preferred method over `[]`:

```
if (auto it = mymap.find("joe") != mymap.end())
{
  make_phone_call(it->second);
}
```

This is particular to ordered and unordered maps, which are unique among the associative containers for providing the intrusive `[]`-operator.

For unordered maps, the lookup time is constant on average.